# Pythonic way to pass input variables to fstrings in another file

Tags: python

I have a project for my company where I need to go to an internal website that downloads an excel file with factory data.  I have two files link_file.py that stores the links to the websites and main.py. This script compares two factories to each other and I need to input different factory codes for each run so I was wondering, what is the most pythonic way to get variables from the main.py file to the dynamic http addresses?

Currently I have fstrings in the main.py file but it looks cluttered with all of the links:

```
#main.py

import webbrowser

link1 = f"www.factorycode.com/{factory_code1}"
link2 = f"www.factorycode.com/{factory_code2}"

factory_code1 = "abc"
factory_code2 = "xyz"

webbrowser.open(link1)
webbrowser.open(link2)
```

I tried a solution using os and .format() but it still looks cluttered.

```
# link_file.py
link1 = f"www.factorycode.com/{factory_code1}"
link2 = f"www.factorycode.com/{factory_code2}"

# main.py
import link_file
import webbrowser
import os

factory_code1 = "abc"
factory_code2 = "xyz"

link_file.link1.format(factory_code1= factory_code1)
link_file.link2.format(factory_code2= factory_code2)

webbrowser.open(link1)
webbrowser.open(link2)
```

Comment: `from main import factory_code1, factory_code2, ...`

Comment: The assignments to `link1` and `link2` have to be after you assign `factory_code1` and `factory_code2`.

Comment: Start with defining *lists* of links, factory codes, etc, instead of individually named variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# link_file.py
link_prefix = "www.factorycode.com/"

# main.py
from link_file import link_prefix
import webbrowser

factory_code1 = "abc"
factory_code2 = "xyz"

link1 = f'{link_prefix}{factory_code1}'
link2 = f'{link_prefix}{factory_code2}'

webbrowser.open(link1)
webbrowser.open(link2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) are for.

```
def open_link(code):
    link = f"www.factorycode.com/{code}"
    webbrowser.open(link)

codes = ['abc', 'xyz', 'def', 'jkl']
for code in codes:
    open_link(code)
```